2 patterns in Makefile target
This makefile can generate images for each page of PDF documents:
%.pdf:
  wget http:/example.com/$@

doc_0-page_0.png: doc_0.pdf
  convert "$^[0]" $@

doc_0-page_1.png: doc_0.pdf
  convert "$^[1]" $@

doc_1-page_0.png: doc_1.pdf
  convert "$^[0]" $@

doc_1-page_1.png: doc_1.pdf
  convert "$^[1]" $@

Can I add more documents and pages without adding more rules?

How do you know how many pages are in a document?

Hi @MadScientist the number of pages could be obtained manually (e.g. opening in a PDF viewer). If the user requests a number that it is too high (e.g doc_0-page_999.png) it will fail.

You can create a text file with as many rules as needed by using an external script and then load that file into main makefile. Something like:
list_of_recipes.mk: source_file_which_would_tell_how_many_recipes_are_needed
     recipe_generation $< $@

include list_of_recipes.mk

For detailed explanation of include, read here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include

It seems a viable option. Also, it is easier for the user than, for example, telling them to run an invented './configure.py > Makefile'. However, I would like to know if there is a way just with make

With an assist from qpdf
and GNU seq you can use GNU make,
# Invoke as: make -j thepdf=path/to/some.pdf

SHELL ::= /bin/sh
thepdfstem ::= $(notdir $(basename $(thepdf)))
all-png-files ::= $(shell \
  npages=$$(qpdf --show-npages $(thepdf)); \
  seq -f "./$(thepdfstem)-%0$${#npages}.0f.png" $${npages};)
all-pdf-files ::= $(patsubst %.png,%.pdf,$(all-png-files))

.PHONY : all
all : $(all-png-files)

$(all-png-files) : ./%.png : ./%.pdf ; \
    convert $< $@

# split PDF to single pages
$(all-pdf-files) &: $(thepdf) ; \
    qpdf --split-pages $< '$(thepdfstem)-%d.pdf'

Using GNU make 4.3+ here for the
grouped
target (&:).
Note that the %d part of qpdf's format string automatically
zero-pads numbers to the required width, whereas seq's ditto
is explicit (${#npages}).

Based on the question I assume the desire is to generate a PNG of one specific page of a given PDF file, based on the command line argument name, not to generate PNGs for every page.

@MadScientist: Could be, I posted this as an outline.
